# Insert Json response in HTML table using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I need to insert my json response to html table.I am able populate data in UI but it is printing the data in UI only not added in table.

Below the code I am using. How to insert my data into table columns?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="http_response" class="table table-bordred table-bordred table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Response</th>
    </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Mac</td>
        <td>Parameter Name</td>
        <td>Response</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

   //JS FIle
    var tr;
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + mac + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].parameter_name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].status + "</td>")    

$('#http_response').append(tr);
```

Comment: What does your current method give you, that is not working as you expect? You need to add to a tbody tag

Comment: result has json response.I am getting values as well.But it is not placing table instead it is hiding table printing data in UI.I need to place this data into table.

Comment: check your browser console for errors

Comment: No errors showing.getting results in UI 5C:E3: Device.Device 200

Comment: This data has to be placed in table instead it is printing data into UI

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vm1w2xej/

Comment: What does your data look like? Or are you getting the data asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restructure your *table* little bit. You can have a *tbody* to append *tr*:

```js
//JS FIle
var result = {response:{parameter_name: 'param1', status: 'OK'}}
var tr,mac = 'MacTEST';
tr = $('<tr/>');
tr.append("<td>" + mac + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].parameter_name + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].status + "</td>")    

$('#http_response tbody').append(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="http_response" class="table table-bordred table-bordred table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Mac</th>
        <th>Parameter Name</th>
        <th>Response</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It still worked. I did not even bother posting an answer but made a fiddle instead

Comment: @mplungjan, you are right.....I just wanted to let OP know the proper design of a table....

Comment: Thanks.#http_response tbody .tbody is required?